# CSS Select Last Span Element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this CSS code:

```css
span.input:last-child {
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    49% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 0.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    49% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 0.0; }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    49% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

and I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="tc">Some More Text</div>
<br>
<div class="content">
    Hello<br>
    <span class="input">_</span><br>
    <span class="input">_</span><br>
</div>
```

The problem is, the last `span.input` doesn't animate at all. How do I make it work using only CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the last child of the `.content` div is a `<br>` element. And `:last-child` is not matching the `<span>`.

[`element:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo class represents the **last child** of its parent matching the `element`.

You could use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) pseudo class to select the last `<span>` element, as follows:

```css
span.input:last-of-type {
    /* styles goes here... */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6NcU9/)**.

However **note** that neither `:last-of-type` nor `:last-child` pseudo classes respect the `.input` class names, they look directly into the *children tree* of the parent not to a list of `element.class`.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type)**:

> The `:last-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the **last** sibling
>   of its **type** in the list of children of its parent element.

It's worth noting that `:last-of-type` pseudo class [is supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

---

Alternatively in this particular instance, you could use [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` *(which is supported in [IE7+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility))* to select the second `span.input` element as follows:

```css
span.input ~ span.input {
    /* styles goes here... */
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6NcU9/1/)**.